# LTSpice - PMOS Gate not turning on

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, charging, pmos

My question is why is the M2 PMOS FET not turning on when Vchrg_ctrl is LOW? My problem is Vload never goes high to charge the Capacitor C1.

I think I am missing something very silly here. Thank you for your help.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you used a generic PMOS device. What sort of model is associated with PMOS in your simulation? I think you would be better off with a specific PMOS device, just as you used a specific part number for the NMOS transistor. Also, it looks like you have the source and drain swapped...make sure the highest circuit voltage is connected to the PMOS source and body.